# How to to dynamically generated elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the jQuery plugin dForm to dynamically generate form fields.

For events, I know I can access those fields with

```
$(document).on("click","#id", function(){});
```

But if I want to, say

```
$("#id").after("<div></div>");
```

Then how do I do that? I've tried

```
$("#id").after("<div></div>").trigger("create");
```

Even though I don't really understand what it does, to no avail.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish.  Are you trying to fire an event? Add an element to the DOM? something else?

Comment: `.after("<div></div>")` should be creating the empty div element, no need to "trigger" anything.

Comment: Is this what your're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/pmzDE/?

Comment: Sorry if the question was unclear. I want to do something like: '$("#id").after("<div></div>");' It doesnt work right now, presumably because jQuery cant find the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there's some confusion on what the event delegation is actually doing. The reason you're using `.on()` is because the event handler is being processed at DOM ready but your dynamic element doesn't exist. Now, when you're going to append to dynamic content, there's no need for event delegation, since when you run the `append` command, you should be targeting an element that exists on the page, whether it be dynamically or there from the start.

So, say you create a div dynamically with the ID of `test`. You can append to this div with a simple `$("#test").append("<span>see, new span</span>");`, since by the time you run this command, the element exists. I hope this helps.

Comment: So there is no difference in an element was added dynamically or from the original HTML?

Comment: Nope, you'd target it the same way. You would only use `.on()` if you want to process an event on that dynamic element. But simply targeting for an append is the same as always. @SatoBolin

Comment: Okay, thanks for enlightening me. I guess my confusion stems from the fact that right now, .on(click) works, and $("#test").append("<span>see, new span</span>"); doesnt. So don't understand what could be the problem.

Comment: Does `#test` exist on the page when you run that command? @SatoBolin

Comment: Ahh @SatoBolin -- The problem is the `$.get` call is an async call, so it tries to append before that call is done. Move your `append` statement into the `.get` callback (right after the `.dform(data)` call)

Comment: Jeez, I totally forgot about that. Thanks a lot! Way too tired right now!

Answer (score 1):

This works because it's responding to an *event*:

```
$(document).on('click', '#id', function(){});
```

The reason is because events traverse the entire DOM structure, from the specific element all the way up to the parent document/window.  So in this case jQuery assigns the event listener to the `document` instead of the element, and then filters events by the selector.  So even if elements are dynamically added after the fact, they'll still be caught because they still pass their events up to `document`.

This, however, isn't responding to an event:

```
$('#id').after('<div></div>');
```

This is just selecting an element, performing an action, and then it's done.  So if that element isn't on the DOM, that action isn't performed.

There's really no way around this.  If you want every `$('#id')` to append a `'<div></div>'` then any time you remove the `id` element and re-add it, you need to call that line of code again.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear enough but only from a guess I think you want to dynamically add a `div` and also want to register an `event` for that `div`, if this is the case then you may do it like this way too, but there are other ways as well.

```
$("#id").after($("<div/>", {
    'id':'test',
    'click':function() { alert ("Clicked!"); }
}));
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/pmzDE/2/)

Another approach to do this (Keep the event handler registered like this using `#test`)

```
$(document).on("click", "#test", function(){
    alert ("Clicked!");
});
```

Insert the new `div`

```
$("#id").after($("<div/>", { 'id':'test'}));
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/pmzDE/3/)

Also, if you want to dynamically create/insert a new `div` and want to trigger the `click` event on this new `div` just right after you insert it, then you may try this

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on("click","#test", function(){
        alert ("Clicked!");
    });

    // insert a new div with id 'test' and invoke click event immediately
    var div = $("<div/>", { 'id':'test'});
    $("#id").after(div);
    div.trigger('click');
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/pmzDE/4/)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'd like to do something like: $("#test").append("<span>see, new span</span>"); It's just that it doesnt work for me right now.

Comment: [This works](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/pmzDE/6/), new `span` is inserted in the new `div#test`.